# excel - read cell which is last cell in colomn A and assosiate with different cell of same row, column C

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Hi need some help of Excel guru please. [Excel sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OkTDE.png)

Formula would do something like this: 
if Last enty in column A is last enty then show B of the same row

So basicaly the E1 should be empty, but if I add text for B5 then E1 should display what is in B5.
And if I add new device in A6 then it should read B6 and so on.

To find last cell I use  =INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,INDEX(MAX((Sheet1!A:A<>"")*(ROW(Sheet1!A:A))),0)).

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
=INDEX(B:B,COUNTA(A:A))
```

Comment: I think not searching for last entry in a row

Answer (score 0):

Figured out my self when I put all on paper

=LOOKUP(2,1/(Sheet1!A:A<>""),Sheet1!B:B)

Answer (score 0):

Or you may try this...

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH("zzz",A:A))
```